# moving a picture to the right in html

Tags: html, styles

I'm doing a portfolio for freecodecamp and i'm trying to get my image and the the phrase side by side, picture on the right and description on the left. How do i line them up next to each other and keep them the same distance even when I shrink the page?

I'm trying to copy and paste the html but when I do it puts my page here, not the code.

Comment: Indent everything by four spaces or use the code sample `{}` button in the toolbar when editing your question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ is also a nifty tool for sharing html/js/css code